# Morse Code Translation

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have an ArrayList containing the morse code letters from A to Z in order and an ArrayList containing the regular alphabet from A to Z in order, what would be the best way to take a user input and translate that by using these two ArrayLists?

Comment: I think the best way is to use something like Map

Comment: Parallel arrays/lists are bad.  [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) are good.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Map<MorseCode, Character>`, iterate through the morse codes entered by the user, and for each morse code, get the associated Character in the map. If you want to translate into the other direction, use a `Map<Character, MorseCode>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `HashMap<String,String>` with morseCode as key and the translation as value? 
You could then use `map.get(key)? and it directly returns the translation with no huge cost of performance.

The cost of accessing the `Map` is O(1). Finding the translation i a `List` has O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Map would be best option here, but if you have to use Lists you can use `indexOf(E element)` method. It will return index of element or -1 in case if list wont contain element. Then you can use `get(int index)` to get element at specified position.

So something like that should do the trick for letter->morseCode

```
int index = letterList.indexOf(yourCharacter);
if (index >= 0)
    morse = morseCodeList.get(index);
```

or reverse it to find morse->letter.